# What's the meaning of the colored edge?

Tags: edit-mode

I've made a classroom scene in 3dmax and exported it(*.fbx) to import in Blender.

After importing it, when I edit it I found that there are two kinds of edges.

Picture's here.

[image]

1. What's the meaning of the green colored edges?
2. Why some of edges are colored while others are not?

Due to Liked answer, I understood the meaning of colored edge.(question 1)

But still I don't know why colored edges(blue edge = sharp edge) exist in my work.(question 2)

I just exported a scene from 3dsmax and imported it to blender.

As you see in my picture, some of blue line need not be sharp, and I did nothing with it to be sharp.

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question per post. If you have a different issue make a new post, ask as many as necessary

Comment: @duarte OK thank you